# pandoc output to markdown with _ for italic instead of *

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm going to translate textile texts to markdown.
Sometimes I found strong and emphasis mixed like this in textile `_*abc* def_`

It's translateted in markdown to `***abc* def*` that's not very easy to read.
What can I do to translate it to `_**abc** def_` (all italics to `_` and bold to `**`) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the pandoc [markdown writer currently](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Markdown.hs#L783) always uses `*...*` for emphasis, never underscores. You can ask on [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss) for an option to be included...

For now, you could also write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) which replaces emphasis elements with some special character, then after pandoc has exported the document run a script to replace the special character back to an underscore.

Comment: I did it by converting to html, replace `<em>` with ToCoNvErT, then convert from html to markdown and replace ToCoNvErT to _.

Comment: @mb21 Could you please clarify if its still like this (7 years later)?

Comment: @Porcupine stil the same. pandoc is not a markdown pretty printer, so this probably won't change anytime soon.